Zero-density results and partial RH
In a couple of papers regarding explicit zero-density results of $\zeta(s)$, such as Kadiri, Lumley, and Ng - Explicit zero density for the Riemann zeta function, I have seen that they take a parameter $H \in (k, H_0)$ for some $k \geq 0$, where $H_0 = 3\cdot10^{12}$ is the current best value that comes from the partial verification of the Riemann Hypothesis, and this parameter $H$ appears in their bound for $N(\sigma, T)$. Why not just take $H_0$? Shouldn't that have one less parameter to worry about?

To answer this question, it would help to know what papers you consulted.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.12263

Re, thanks; I have edited that in.

Because the parameter $H$ appears in both an increasing and decreasing term in, e.g. Theorem 1.1, so it may not be optimal to take $H=H_0$. A further optimisation has to be done to see which value of $H\in (k,H_0)$ gives the best bounds. (which that paper does, giving their bound of (1.7), which has no $H$)

I see what you mean. I was just thinking why the parameter was introduced in the first place. I guess they went through the entire argument and proof and introduced it later as is somewhat evident from their latter half of the paper. So, without the optimization, it will not be possible to go from (1.6) to (1.7)?

This kind of parametrisation is standard in explicit results and often taking $H=H_0$ or close to, gives the best result asymptotically but not necessarily for all $T\geq 2$.
In the paper you have referenced, the choice of $H$ is rather straightforward and one can see in Section 5 that the authors have just set $H=H_0-1$ for the result (1.7) and $H=H_0-10^{-6}$ for the result (1.6). Certainly, one cannot take $H=H_0$ exactly otherwise one could have $T-H=0$ which would blow up the main term in (1.6):
$$\frac{(T-H)(\log T)}{2\pi d}\log\left(1+\frac{C_1(\log(kT))^{2\sigma}(\log T)^{4(1-\sigma)}T^{\frac{8}{3}(1-\sigma)}}{T-H}\right).$$
Thus, ultimately some optimisation is still required to balance the terms which increase/decrease with $H$ but it is not a significant part of the result.
A paper which I find more illustrative for the same phenomena is this paper by J. Büthe, where he estimates the error term in the prime number theorem $|\psi(x)-x|$ and uses a similar parameter $T\leq H_0$. Ultimately, his argument results in a bound (in a simplified notation)
$$|\psi(x)-x|\leq f(x,T)+g(x,T),$$
where $f(x,T)$ is asymptotically large in $x$ and decreases with $T$, whereas $g(x,T)$ is asymptotically small in $x$ but increases with $T$. Thus, if $x$ is large enough one should always select $T=H_0$. However, in his Table 2 one sees that choosing $T$ smaller than $H_0$ gives the best result for small values of $x$.

I see, thanks. Yes, I did see the notes they mentioned in the beginning of Section 5 later as you mentioned, and precisely so. I guess I overlooked the fact that they are taking $T \geq H_0$, in which case they could have $T = H_0$ and that would blow up the main term in (1.6) as you pointed out. I am aware of the other paper you mentioned; I will have to look it up too. Thanks again.
